# reduce by matching lower case keys in spark rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have an rdd of (key, value) pairs, the keys are string and the values are the number of occurrences of the strings.

```
words.take(10)

Out[98]: [('The', 2767),
 ('Project', 83),
 ('the', 3),
 ('of', 14941),
 ('Leo', 4),
 ('is', 3245),
 ('use', 80),
 ('anyone', 191),
 ('Of', 25),
 ('at', 4235)]
```

I want to match keys by key.lower(), sum their values, and also keep the original values for each upper\lower case key.

In addition, I want to filter out non-repeating keys.

so my output for the example above of words.take(10) will be:

```
 [(('The', 2767),('the', 3),2770),(('Of', 25),('of', 14941),14966)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `collect_list` and `filter` the data as below

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [
    ('The', 2767),
    ('Project', 83),
    ('the', 3),
    ('of', 14941),
    ('Leo', 4),
    ('is', 3245),
    ('use', 80),
    ('anyone', 191),
    ('Of', 25),
    ('at', 4235)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*["word", "count"])

df.groupby(f.lower("word").alias("word")) \
  .agg(f.collect_list(f.struct("word", "count")).alias("list"), f.sum("count").alias("sum")) \
  .filter(f.size("list") > 1) \
  .select("list", "sum") \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------+-----+
|list                   |sum  |
+-----------------------+-----+
|[{The, 2767}, {the, 3}]|2770 |
|[{of, 14941}, {Of, 25}]|14966|
+-----------------------+-----+
```

Comment: please import function as `from pyspark.sql import functions as f`